# R studio cannot debug functions

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I have written a function `f` which throws some dimension erros. I want to debug it, but if I place a breakpoint inside the function and run it, the debugger does not stop at the break-point. If I copy the function content to a script, place the breakpoint at the same place and run the script, the debugger works.

Comment: RStudio distinguishes between *editor breakpoints* and [browser breakpoints](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#entering-debug-mode-stopping) created by using the function [browser()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/browser). Perhaps you are using the former but would prefer the functionality of the latter.

Comment: Thank you so much!!